# Accessing Dropbox login page through lynx / elinks via ssh on aws

Tags: dropbox, aws, lynx, javascript

I'm trying to install Dropbox in *an entirely text-based Linux environment,* following the instructions available on [Dropbox wiki](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/install-dropbox-in-an-entirely-text-based-linux-environment), which states:

> - Use a command-line browser (lynx)
> - Navigate to the dropbox website in lynx.  lynx    https://dropbox.com/
> - Log in to your dropbox account
> - (...)

I've tried accessing the provided URL with use of [elinks](/questions/tagged/elinks) and lynx and it's hopeless. It's not possible to log in via this page anywhere:

[image: Lynx results]

I've tried navigating to `(BUTTON) Sign in` but Lynx only returns message:

> DISABLED form submit button. Use UP or DOWN arrows or tab to move off.

The Elinks render looks *slightly* better but it's not possible to pass through the login screen (i.e. after providing the details in the form the page only refreshes):

[image: eLinks]

---

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS on [aws](/questions/tagged/aws). I have tried Lynx Version 2.8.8pre.4 (04 Feb 2014) and ELinks 0.12pre6.

Comment: using the Dropbox python API is not a suitable alternative for you ?

Comment: @mazs Thanks for your comment, it could be. There is also [dropbox_uploader](https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader) [tag:bash] script that I could use, having said that, I was thinking that there is a way of just following through the available instructions. I would imagine that someone was able to do at least once.